# Update value each time new rows is created

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have two tables: `config(last_inserted_id)` and `element(id)` is there any chance to get the **last inserted id** any time when new rows are created in `element` table and execute a update in column `last_inserted_id` at `config` table?

I have wrote this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_CONFIG_VALUES AFTER INSERT ON element
    BEGIN
        UPDATE config SET last_inserted_id = last_insert_id();
    END;
END;
```

Is that right? What happen if I delete a row in `element` table? Should the value get updated in `config` table or not" How I avoid this?

**`config` table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cmplatform`.`isrl_config` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `logo_address` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `rif` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `address` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
  `last_retention_number` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEST this ( Not tested)

```
CREATE TRIGGER element_inserted_tg AFTER INSERT ON element
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO count FROM config;
    IF count == 1
        UPDATE config SET last_inserted_id = NEW.id;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO config VALUES (NEW.id);
    END IF;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER element_deleted_tg AFTER DELETE ON element
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE config SET last_inserted_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM element);
END;
```

Comment: Didn't work if table `config` hasn't values, any solution for this one or the table need to has at least one row?

Comment: Is very simple. In BEGIN ... END. Write some code to check whether a row exists in config. If yes, process UPDATE, else process INSERT.

Comment: Hmm I'm not a MySQL expert could you add this to your answer?

Comment: I don't know config table design. I assume that it has one column and it has 1 row to store last inserted element id. Check updated version.

Comment: See the post updated `1` should be changed? I'm getting error #1064 will trying to update the trigger from phpMyAdmin

Comment: It seems you designed Config table wrong because there is only ONE last inserted id so how do you store it if config table has a lot rows?

Comment: I removed the `id` column and there is only one row but problem still

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is traditional way to do this requirement but not unique way. Another way is process it in your data access code. Let say that you have a DAO method to create new Element, you can get the id of element created and update it into last_inserted_id. If you do this way, you have to makesure there is ONLY ONE THREAD calling insert element method at a time.

Comment: I know I can get this done at code level but I don't give the responsibility to the code instead I want to execute this on DB so this is what I'm looking for

Comment: so trigger is your way. I think so.

Comment: Yes trigger is my way but I have no idea in how to do this and I asking here for some help

Comment: Test my new solution.